# how to extract element from xml/string

Tags: jquery

i am using 3rd party api and this is what is its returning me:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
\u000a
<errorNotification>
\u000a\u0009
<message>invalid company code<\/message>
\u000a
<\/errorNotification>
```

my question is: how can just extract the `<message>` from the above string/xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var xml = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>\u000a<errorNotification>\u000a\u0009<message>invalidcompanycode<\/message>\u000a<\/errorNotification>',
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
message= $xml.find( 'message' ).text();


alert(message);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ycLms/

Comment: i am using jquery 1.4 and here is what the error i am getting `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: @Abu Hamzah `jQuery.parseXML()` added in version 1.5 of jQuery. Check if you can use this version with your current code without have any error.